# What is the best approach to build a Google App Engine store locator type of application?

Tags: google-app-engine, geolocation, geospatial

I am trying to build a store locator type of application that will automatically display the nearby stores on Google Map as markers. Because the limitation of GQL, traditional way of doing geo query is not possible. I came across three options and want to ask if anyone had any experience with them and which one works better. Thanks!

- [Geomodel](http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/)
- [Mutiny project](http://code.google.com/p/mutiny)
- Geodatastore

Comment: If by the "traditional way", you mean doing range queries on latitude and longitude, this isn't scalable in any database - that's why spatial extensions exist for RDBMSes, with spatial indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience doing geo queries, but it is always helpful to use the activity meters that Google Code has.

At a glance it looks like the first one is your best bet.

Comment: That is what I've learned so far as well. Probably make sense to go with the more active project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Performing_Location-Based_Searches) now supports Geosearch.
It can retrieve results within a given radius and sort them by distance, so it should work for what you want to do.